# Google Sheets: Create formula that auto-updates for new entries & sums cells in other columns

Tags: google-sheets, sum, formulas

I have a Google Form which feeds values into a Google Sheet. As part of my analysis, I need to `SUM()` together, in a new `Column Q`, entries from columns H, I, J, K, and L.  I do not want totals of these columns, but `Q1= H1+I1+J1+K1+L1`, then `Q2= H2+I2+J2+K2+L2`, etc.

The sticking point is that I also want this formula to automatically populate `Column Q` as new data is added to H, I, J, K, and L.  Is there a solution for this?  Can I do this with an array formula?

Comment: Have you tried using [ARRAYFORMULA()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ARRAYFORMULA to do this.  You cannot use a SUM() inside the ARRAYFORMULA, but you can use + such as H1:H + I1:I.  So testing to make sure H has data and then using that to add your columns, you would get:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(H1:H),,H1:H + I1:I + J1:J + K1:K + L1:L))
```

The IF() allows us to apply this only to rows with data in column H.  We determine if H is blank and if it is, we return nothing.  Note that this is different than putting "" in for the TRUE option as "" becomes a value in the cell.

**Reading the Formula**

This basically reads as "For each row in the spreadsheet, if cell H is blank, do nothing. If cell H1 is not blank, return the result of adding cells H, I, J, K and L from this same row."

Comment: Thanks, Karl!  This worked great.  I am wondering what the second comma does in the formula?  The two commas after (H1:H)?

Comment: The commas are part of the IF() function.  IF(condition, return_if_action_is_true, return_if_action_is_false)  By leave the return value for a True condition to Nothing we return nothing.  This is different than other spreadsheet applications were "" would return nothing.  Hopefully my edit helps explain this.